# NopCommerce 3.30 Image browser

Tags: c#, image, nopcommerce

Hi please is some way to add image browser to NopCommerce 3.30?
I found on NC forum, this version have not image browser, but post is 2 years old. 
Is there someone who solves the same problem, and found a better solution than upgrade? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version of nopCommerce and copy appropriate functionality from it to your version 3.30. Please have a look at the following files and directories:

1. Nop.Admin\Controllers\RoxyFilemanController.cs
2. Nop.Admin\Controllers\JbimagesController.cs
3. Nop.Web\Content\Roxy_Fileman
4. Nop.Admin\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\RichEditor.cshtml